# Google App Scripts embedding websites as a fullscreen iframe in google docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Is it possible to create an app script that creates and opens an iframe, with a different website inside of it, when you open a google doc? For example,

1. Open a specific google doc
2. The app script runs
3. a full screen iframe appears on the same page, with a completely different website inside of it
   3a) website is still functional, pointer lock, sound, keyboard interaction, etc?

I've tried to make one but I cant figure it out.
Please let me know any possible options!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As long as the website that you're framing doesn't disallow iframing, you can use `<iframe>` with [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output) to show other websites in a [modal dialog or in a sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs).